# MySQL Global Triggers for a connection

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to create a trigger that will listen for any insert or update for one database connection/instance (all schemas)?

Here is my business case:

- I have multiple schemas on one MySQL server.
- Each of these schemas has multiple tables.
- All of the tables have a 'lastChanged' datetime column.
- I need to update the 'lastChanged' column in a table whenever an update or insert occurs on that table.

So to summarize, I am looking to see if it is possible to create a global rule that would make it so I do not need to create a trigger for every table, in every schema.

I haven't much experience with triggers, so if you think of something other than a trigger as the answer for catching these events and updating rows in corresponding tables that would be a fantastic answer as well!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a single trigger.

However, if you change the `lastChanged` column from [`DATETIME` to `TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) then you can use the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` feature to set the value automatically on any insert or update.

One tradeoff is that the `TIMESTAMP` data type can only support values from 1970 to 2038, so you can't use that if you need to store values outside that range.

Since you are looking to make this as simple as possible, and you said all of the tables already have a column named `lastChanged`, you can consider using `information_schema` to generate the alter table statements you need, and then execute them all at once.

Something like this:

```
select concat('alter table ',
   t.table_schema,
   '.',
   t.table_name,
   ' modify column ',
   c.column_name,
   ' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;') as ddl
into outfile '/tmp/lastChanged.sql'
from information_schema.columns c
  inner join information_schema.tables t 
    on t.table_schema = c.table_schema and t.table_name = c.table_name
where c.table_schema = database()
and c.data_type = 'datetime'
and c.column_name = 'lastChanged'
and t.table_type = 'base table';

\. /tmp/lastChanged.sql
```